# How to filter on a nested object property in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter, filtering

The following returns all `arrProps` that have a matching `arrValues` value:

```
const arr = [
{ arrProps: [{name: '1', prop2: 'aaa'}], arrValues: ['apple', 'orange'] },
{ arrProps: [{name: '2', prop2: 'bbb'}], arrValues: ['taco', 'orange' ] },
{ arrProps: [{ name: '3', prop2: 'ccc' }], arrValues: ['fish', 'apple', 'orange'] }
];

const result = arr
  .flatMap(({ arrValues }) => arrValues )  // all values
  .filter((value, index, coll) => coll.indexOf(value) === index) //unique values
  .reduce((acc, value) => {
      const parentProp = arr      // name, prop2, arrValues
          .filter((obj) => obj.arrValues.includes(value))
          .map((obj) => obj.arrProps[0].name);
          //.map((obj) => [{ source: obj.arrProps[0].name, value: obj.arrValues[0], sourceID: null}]);

      acc[value] = (acc[value] ? [...acc[value], parentProp] : [parentProp])
      .join(',');
      acc[value] = parentProp
      
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result);
console.table(result);
```

[image]

I need to add additional properties to arrValues, thereby using objects rather than values:

```
const arr = [
    { arrProps: [{ name: '1', prop2: 'aaa' }], arrValues: [{ symbol: 'apple', id: '1.apple' }, {symbol: 'orange', id: '1.orange'}] },
    { arrProps: [{ name: '2', prop2: 'bbb' }], arrValues: [{ symbol: 'fish', id: '2.fish' }, { symbol: 'pizza', id: '2.pizza' }, { symbol: 'red', id: '2.red' }] },
    { arrProps: [{ name: '3', prop2: 'ccc' }], arrValues: [{ symbol: 'grape', id: '3.grape'}, { symbol: 'apple', id: '3.apple' }] },
];
```

From simply `'apple'`, I need to add some additional uniquely identifying values, i.e. `{ symbol: 'apple', id: '1.apple' }`

I'm sure it's in here:

```
aMap.filter((value, index, coll) => coll.indexOf(value) === index) // <--- filter issue
```

Which is returning the object (previous data model, just the value 'apple', 'orange'...):

```
Array(7) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    [[Prototype]]: Array(0)
    length: 7
    0: Object {symbol: "apple", id: "1.apple"}
    1: Object {symbol: "orange", id: "1.orange"}
    2: Object {symbol: "fish", id: "2.fish"}
    3: Object {symbol: "pizza", id: "2.pizza"}
    4: Object {symbol: "red", id: "2.red"}
    5: Object {symbol: "grape", id: "3.grape"}
    6: Object {symbol: "apple", id: "3.apple"}
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

I'm having a heck of a time trying to filter on `arrValues[0].symbol`.  I then need to append `arrValues[0].id` to the results.  I figure createing a new object with arrProps and the unique ID would be best.

**So in the case of `apple`, the first column should render `{parent: arrProps[0], id: arrValues[0].id}`, etc.**

**--- UPDATE ---**

Rather than just showing the name of arrPorps[0].name, I need an object returned, as per the last line above (a change from the original question).

I had thought about finding some way to append arrProps to the output but got stuck there.  Since I can hydrate the data model, I added some additional identifying properties to `arrValues[]` (wait, does this and `arrProps[]` really need to be an array, it's just an object - refactor?):

```
const arr = [
    { arrProps: [{ name: '1', prop2: 'aaa' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '1', symbol: 'apple', id: '1.apple' }, {exchange: '1', symbol: 'orange', id: '1.orange' }] },
    { arrProps: [{ name: '2', prop2: 'bbb' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '2', symbol: 'fish', id: '2.fish' }, { exchange: '2', symbol: 'pizza', id: '2.pizza' }, { exchange: '2', symbol: 'red', id: '2.red' }] },
    { arrProps: [{ name: '3', prop2: 'ccc' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '3', symbol: 'grape', id: '3.grape' }, { exchange: '3', symbol: 'apple', id: '3.apple' }] },
];
```

Then changed the output, creating an output object,

From: `.map(({ arrProps }) => arrProps[0].name)`

To:  `.map(({ arrValues }) => [{ exchange: arrValues[0].exchange, symbol: arrValues[0].symbol, id: arrValues[0].id }]);`

Whole updated code:

```js
    const arr = [
        { arrProps: [{ name: '1', prop2: 'aaa' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '1', symbol: 'apple', id: '1.apple' }, {exchange: '1', symbol: 'orange', id: '1.orange' }] },
        { arrProps: [{ name: '2', prop2: 'bbb' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '2', symbol: 'fish', id: '2.fish' }, { exchange: '2', symbol: 'pizza', id: '2.pizza' }, { exchange: '2', symbol: 'red', id: '2.red' }] },
        { arrProps: [{ name: '3', prop2: 'ccc' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '3', symbol: 'grape', id: '3.grape' }, { exchange: '3', symbol: 'apple', id: '3.apple' }] },
    ];
    
    const objectValues = arr.flatMap(({ arrValues }) => arrValues);  // not necessary if we refactor, removing these arrays?
    const values = objectValues.map(({ symbol }) => symbol);
    const uniqueValues = [...new Set(values)];
    const result = uniqueValues.reduce((acc, value) => {
        acc[value] = arr
            .filter(({ arrValues }) => {
                const symbols = arrValues.map(({ symbol }) => symbol)
                return symbols.includes(value);
            })
            //.map(({ arrProps }) => arrProps[0].name)
            .map(({ arrValues }) => [{ exchange: arrValues[0].exchange, symbol: arrValues[0].symbol, id: arrValues[0].id }]);
            //.join(',');
        return acc;
    }, {});
    
    console.log("RAW:" + JSON.stringify(result));
    
    console.log(result);
    console.table(result);
    
    Object.entries(result).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        console.log(`      ----] The value '${k}' exists in:`);
        console.table(JSON.stringify(v));
        //console.log("The pair: ", k)
        ////console.log("The value: ", v)
        v.forEach(_pool => console.log(`
            Exchange: ${_pool[0].exchange}
            symbol: ${_pool[0].symbol}
            ID: ${_pool[0].id}
        `));
    })
```

Two problems:

1. I think the arrays are not necessary in the data model
2. The output data is wrong.

> ```
> {
>    "apple":[
>       [
>          {
>             "exchange":"1",
>             "symbol":"apple",
>             "id":"1.apple"
>          }
>       ],
>       [
>          {
>             "exchange":"3",
>             "symbol":"grape",   // should be "apple"
>             "id":"3.grape"      // should be "3.apple"
>          }
>       ]
>    ],
>    "orange":[
>       [
>          {
>             "exchange":"1",
>             "symbol":"apple",   // should be "orange"
>             "id":"1.apple"      // should be "1.orange"
>          }
>       ]
>    ],
>    "fish":[
>       [
>          {
>             "exchange":"2",
>             "symbol":"fish",
>             "id":"2.fish"
>          }
>       ]
>    ],
>    "pizza":[
>       [
>          {
>             "exchange":"2",
>             "symbol":"fish",   // should be pizza
>             "id":"2.fish"      // should be 2.pizza
>          }
>       ]
>    ],
>    "red":[
>       [
>          {
>             "exchange":"2",
>             "symbol":"fish",   // should be "red"
>             "id":"2.fish"      // should be "2.red"
>          }
>       ]
>    ],
>    "grape":[
>       [
>          {
>             "exchange":"3",
>             "symbol":"grape",
>             "id":"3.grape"
>          }
>       ]
>    ]
> }
> ```

**--- UPDATE 2 ---**

Going back to my suspicion of the data being wrong, well, it appears to be.

Rather than each object being named according to its related common word: `apple, orange, fish`, this needs to be parameterized and superfluous arrays removed (pseudocoded object):

```
[{
    itemName: 'apple',
    itemParam2: 'xxx',
    itemPools: [
        { source: '3', symbol: 'apple', id: '3.apple', cost: '0.00' },
        { source: '4', symbol: 'apple', id: '4.apple', cost: '0.00' },
        { source: '4', symbol: 'apple', id: '4b.apple', cost: '0.00' }
      ],
    itemName: 'orange',
    itemParam2: 'yyy',
    itemPools: [
    ...
    itemName: 'fish',
    itemParam2: 'zzz',
    itemPools: [
    ...
}]
```

FYI:  need to verify the result data object to be properly formatted

Actually, `orange` and `fish` should be omited from the model as the itemPools.length is not > 1.

So in addition to the updated model properties, only items where `itemPool.length > 1` should be added.

Without this, I am unable to [find an array item by its property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#finding_an_array_item_object_by_its_property).

To give some future context, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70468432/how-to-add-object-listeners-to-existing-objects-in-javascript).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several approaches, I changed solution. In my opinion, it is now simpler and more versatile.

```js
const arr = [
    { arrProps: [{ name: '1', prop2: 'aaa' }], arrValues: [{ symbol: 'apple', id: '1.apple' }, {symbol: 'orange', id: '1.orange'}] },
    { arrProps: [{ name: '2', prop2: 'bbb' }], arrValues: [{ symbol: 'fish', id: '2.fish' }, { symbol: 'pizza', id: '2.pizza' }, { symbol: 'red', id: '2.red' }] },
    { arrProps: [{ name: '3', prop2: 'ccc' }], arrValues: [{ symbol: 'grape', id: '3.grape'}, { symbol: 'apple', id: '3.apple' }] },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, { arrProps: [{ name }], arrValues }) => {
    arrValues.map(({ symbol }) => symbol)
    .forEach((value) => {
        acc[value] = acc[value] ? `${acc[value]},${name}`: name;
    });
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

If we consider the **previous approach** with the filter, the solution could be as follows:

```js
const arr = [
    { arrProps: [{ name: '1', prop2: 'aaa' }], arrValues: [{ symbol: 'apple', id: '1.apple' }, {symbol: 'orange', id: '1.orange'}] },
    { arrProps: [{ name: '2', prop2: 'bbb' }], arrValues: [{ symbol: 'fish', id: '2.fish' }, { symbol: 'pizza', id: '2.pizza' }, { symbol: 'red', id: '2.red' }] },
    { arrProps: [{ name: '3', prop2: 'ccc' }], arrValues: [{ symbol: 'grape', id: '3.grape'}, { symbol: 'apple', id: '3.apple' }] },
];

const objectValues = arr.flatMap(({ arrValues }) => arrValues);
const values = objectValues.map(({ symbol }) => symbol);
const uniqueValues = [...new Set(values)];
const result = uniqueValues.reduce((acc, value) => {
  acc[value] = arr
    .filter(({ arrValues }) => {
      const symbols = arrValues.map(({ symbol }) => symbol)
      return symbols.includes(value);
    })
    .map(({ arrProps }) => arrProps[0].name)
    .join(',');
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**---UPDATE---**

```js
const arr = [
        { arrProps: [{ name: '1', prop2: 'aaa' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '1', symbol: 'apple', id: '1.apple' }, {exchange: '1', symbol: 'orange', id: '1.orange' }] },
        { arrProps: [{ name: '2', prop2: 'bbb' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '2', symbol: 'fish', id: '2.fish' }, { exchange: '2', symbol: 'pizza', id: '2.pizza' }, { exchange: '2', symbol: 'red', id: '2.red' }] },
        { arrProps: [{ name: '3', prop2: 'ccc' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '3', symbol: 'grape', id: '3.grape' }, { exchange: '3', symbol: 'apple', id: '3.apple' }] },
    ];
    
    
const result = arr.reduce((acc, { arrValues }) => {
    arrValues.forEach((value) => {
        acc[value.symbol] = acc[value.symbol] 
          ? [...acc[value.symbol], value] 
          : [value]; 
    });
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

**---UPDATE 3---**

```js
const arr = [
{ arrProps: [{ name: '1', prop2: 'aaa' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '1', symbol: 'apple', id: '1.apple' }, {exchange: '1', symbol: 'orange', id: '1.orange' }] },
{ arrProps: [{ name: '2', prop2: 'bbb' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '2', symbol: 'fish', id: '2.fish' }, { exchange: '2', symbol: 'pizza', id: '2.pizza' }, { exchange: '2', symbol: 'red', id: '2.red' }] },
{ arrProps: [{ name: '3', prop2: 'ccc' }], arrValues: [{ exchange: '3', symbol: 'grape', id: '3.grape' }, { exchange: '3', symbol: 'apple', id: '3.apple' }] },
];

const reduceArray = (data, poolsCountEdge = 1) => {
  const result = data.reduce((acc, { arrValues }) => {
      arrValues.forEach((value) => {
         const item = acc.find(({ name }) => name === value.symbol);
         if (item) {
           item.pools.push(value);
           item.poolsCount = item.pools.length;
         } else {
           acc.push({ name: value.symbol, poolsCount: 1, pools: [value] }); 
         }
      });
      
      return acc;
  }, []);
  
  return result.filter(({ poolsCount }) => poolsCount > poolsCountEdge)
};

console.log(reduceArray(arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Rather than just a string of .name in the matching outputs, I need an object that contains additional properties.  I refactored the code and data model to include these but appear to be stuck once more.  Please see after `---UPDATE---` above.

Comment: @ElHaix Updated solution to reflect new object structure. See `---UPDATE---` section.

Comment: This is great, thank you.  One last thing:  I only want to add to the model if there a symbol appears more than once - something like `if symbol.count > 1` ?

Comment: @ElHaix Please post the object model you would like to have.

Comment: I knew something didn't look quite right.  Although my initial question was answered (and thank you for that), the output data model needs to be cleaned up.  Please see `--- UPDATE 2---`.  Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @ElHaix Check `---UPDATE 2---` section. Now result is not an object but array of objects. You can easily do all array's manipulation: filter, map, find and so on.

Comment: Thank you.  However the model still contains objects with poolCount: 1.  It should only contain objects with poolCount > 1:  ` { name: 'one', poolsCount: 1, pools: [ [Object] ] },` should not be there.  Is it possible to omit these from the returned model?

Comment: I can do a quick filter with `result.filter(result => result.poolsCount > 1)` which is fine.  Just wondering if the filter could be applied sooner?

Comment: @ElHaix you can just wrap filter in a function.  See `---UPDATE 3---` solution.