# How to add object listeners to existing objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, event-handling, publish-subscribe, subscriber

I have a data model that I am hydrating through a process I control, so I can update its schema and properties if required:

`results:`

```
{
  pizza: [
    { source: '2', symbol: 'pizza', id: '2.pizza', cost: '0.00' },
    { source: '4', symbol: 'pizza', id: '4.pizza', cost: '0.00' }
  ],
  apple: [
    { source: '3', symbol: 'apple', id: '3.apple', cost: '0.00' },
    { source: '4', symbol: 'apple', id: '4.apple', cost: '0.00' },
    { source: '4', symbol: 'apple', id: '4b.apple', cost: '0.00' }
  ]
}
```

For the view, using **React**, I will want to display this data in a table that will update each result's `totalAmount`, updating the table cell for that row.  However, more importantly for now is how to update the model.

Now that we have the initial data model, I need to add event listeners (after we have the model) to each `source` object, each with their own unique endpoint to execute a function.  I can subscribe to a `source` event that fires whenever that source has a change.  When there is a change, I want to update that *source's* `cost`, add all costs for that `result` and update that *result's* `totalAmount` amount but not update any other *totalAmounts* (but we can, but not as elegant).

First question is how to add an object listener only to each `source` object and not update all sources in the model?  For this, I have tried the following from [here](https://coderedirect.com/questions/221168/javascript-event-listener-for-changes-in-an-object-variable), which works in testing for `MyVar.prop1` but I am not sure how I would add something like this to individual `result` sub objects.  Does it have to be applied to the entire model?

```
var MyVar = {
  _prop1: 0,
  get prop1() { return this._prop1; },
  set prop1(value) { this._prop1 = value; /*Listener code can go here*/ }
};
```

Secondly, once a change is detected, the callback should do something like `results["pizza"].totalAmount = {sum of all costs for this object}`.  This would add a `totalAmount` property.  However would it be better to create an empty property to fill in later?

`{ source: '2', symbol: 'pizza', id: '2.pizza', cost: '0.00' },` <== change detected, cost changed to 5.00.

The resulting model for this object would then be:

```
{
  pizza: [
    { source: '2', symbol: 'pizza', id: '2.pizza', cost: '0.00' },
    { source: '4', symbol: 'pizza', id: '4.pizza', cost: '0.00' },
    totalAmount: '5.00'
  ], ...
```

And the table updated with the new values.

Comment: I'd try to stick to one question. You didn't explain what didn't work about using a setter.

Comment: I suggest you create a `Product` class  for each item with a `get totalCost() { return this.ingredients.reduce((total, item) => total + item.cost, 0)}` If you really want to reach to JS values being changed, you probably want to look into `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy`

Comment: You say you're using React. In that case, you should keep your data immutable and don't do assignments to it. Your objects shouldn't change, and there should be no "object listeners". Instead, create a new results object with different values. And instead of putting a `.totalAmount` property on array objects, use a simple `function getTotalAmount(ingredients) { … }` to *derive* the amount from an array.

Comment: @JuanMendes Updated - got the `MyVar.prop1` listener working.  Still doesn't help me in attaching it to my model.  @Bergi:  The initial model is created from a complex process of external calls and having to recreate the `results` object I don't think would be efficient.

Comment: @ElHaix You don't need to recreate it from scratch, you only need to make a copy of it with one value changed. And even if it might not seem efficient at first glance, it's actually not as bad; but what matters is that this approach is *required* by React.

Comment: @Bergi I see.  I am not very familiar with the React data requirements.  I'll do some research into what you are suggesting.  In addition, I realize that my data model is also not correct - incorrect root parameters which is hindering me from finding an array item object by its property (@JuanMendes' `Proxy` suggestion).

Comment: @ElHaix aside from computing total amount, do you need to do side effects on listening to each object changes?

Comment: @JasperBernales If I understand what you are asking, when objects change, I would like to add these to a separate list so I can create a live report on the UI and execute additional functions on them given certain business rules, i.e. `totalAmount` within a range, add logic.  (and thank you all for the prompt suggestions and assistance!)
FYI:  I will be updating the data model to have a common parent parameter, i.e. `itemPools: [...]` rather than `apple`, `pizza`...

Comment: ahh I see. I believe you can achieve what you need with react hooks `useEffect` and `useMemo`.

Comment: @JuanMendes Thank you for the class suggestion.  In C# I would find this simpler.  I'm tackling this in a new question with some issues: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70481482/how-to-process-updated-object-property-values-with-javascript-and-react